# Redirect user to parent page when iframe is accessed directly

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, redirect, lightbox

I am using a jquery lightbox plugin (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to load content using an iframe. The problem is when users access the page directly or via a search engine the page they are taken to is the iframe content itself and not the parent page which loads the iframe.

How can i redirect users who access the iframe directly to be taken to the original page that loads the iframe?

Comment: You might wanna see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248940/redirect-if-the-page-is-iframe) as well
works good if you want to use your url parameters in the redirect url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(window.top.location == window.location){
  window.location = "http://example.com/whatever/page/you/want/them/to/go/to.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to determine if you're in an iframe or not, so this jQuery should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (top != self) {
            window.location = "page_with_iframe.htm";
    }
});
</script>
```