# redirect if the page is iframe

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe, get

Here is what i want to do:

in my blog, comments are shown in a [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) popup using iframe. (eg:- for the post number 2, comments link open an iframe fancybox `comments.php?id=2`)

I want to check whether comments.php is loaded in an iframe and if not, redirect to the respective blog page. i.e. `post.php?id=2`

I checked Google and other sites incl. stackoverflow. but no use. pls help. (this seems to be easy. but it ain't working http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this script in your page. If it is not opened in a frame, it will redirect to `post.php?id=...`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (parent.location==location) {
        location.href = "post.php" + location.search;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking something like

```
if ( document.parent.frames.length > 0 ) {
    document.parent.location = "post.php";
}
```

should work

Comment: It won't pass the querystring to `post.php` so the relevant post won't be shown

Comment: it absolutely will not. that is correct. I left that part to the poster to figure out how to do. After all, learning by doing is one of the best ways to learn. And between our two answers, I imagine they would be able to cobble together the answer they seek.

Comment: Well each to their own I guess. I just like to provide a complete solution where possible.